# I need to create a file in my server and write some contents on it using php

Tags: php, cross-domain

I am using a cross domain request.A request has been made to php file in a server via ajax from another server.From php side Here, I need to create a file and write some contents in that file.My request is reaching perfectly.But I am not able to create a file.Please help

NOTE : ITS A CROSS DOMAIN REQUEST

```
<?php
$filename = "lin.txt";
$data2 = "lin IS HERE";
$newFile= fopen($filename, 'w');
chmod($newFile, 777);
fwrite($newFile, $data2);
fclose($newFile);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put your code here, show what you did, why you did that. It is not a place where you can get free pieces of code without doing something yourself

Comment: And how, exactly, do you expect someone to help you with this?

Comment: prime example of how **NOT** to post a question

Comment: I have written my code.But its not visible here after posting it.Im sorry if I did something wrong

Comment: You might want to give it another thought if coding is really something for you...

Comment: I dont know whats happening.My points are reduced.I have kept my code.Somehow,its not showing.I expect some help

Comment: See, I really have posted my formatted code.But it was not visible to anybody.Anyway, I am sorry for the things which made weird.Why Iam reduced much for this?

Comment: @linn because it was not a good question then people downvote and explain what you should do to make it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In am not sure what are you going to do, because you haven't told us your code. I think this will help you:

```
<?php
$file = 'demo.txt';
$content = "Example\n";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```

The file is `demo.txt` (it is at the same location with the PHP document.

`$content` is the text which will be put on your txt file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My code is available now

Comment: This answer is perfect,if iam sending a data via cross domain, its not possible to create like this.

Comment: Stack overflow was a good help to me.I understood my mistakes and I won't repeat this.I humbly request you to help me to make my account active